# ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP error while using DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my sql query. Here, I am filtering 2 sets of data from 2 different tables using DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE. Oracle SQL loads for very long duration and throws below error. I tried searching for the same error. But the answers doesn't solve my problem. Please let me know if there are any other means to achieve the result.

```
select * from (select ac.account, ph.phone_no
from account ac, phone ph
and ac.account_status = 'OPEN'
and ac.account_type ='1'             
and ac.account_sub_type ='2'
and ac.account = ph.phone_account
order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
where rownum = '1';
```

I see **ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP** error. I need to fetch random account and respective phone_no from account and phone tables everytime i run the query.

Edit: From above query, I need to select 1 random set of account number and phone number from Account table and Phone number table. Note that account number comes from **account** table and Phone number comes from **phone** table.

Sample output would be simply 1 account number and one phone number. Ex: 123456 1234567890

**Edit 2: Sometimes it works, but takes around 40-60 minutes to load 1 set of data which is very unrealistic for my automated test case. Need better alternative.**

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: ROWNUM is a number, not a string.

Comment: am I missing something or are you just combining tables account and phone without joining them? The error itself just means that oracle needs more temp space than is available right now, which indicates your query creates quite a lot of work for the database. If possible, look at the query execution plan and optimize the query. The error is not your root problem, it is just a symptom of an expensive query.

Comment: Done; Please take a look. Thanks Gordon...

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek is correct. Your query produces a cartesian join (all rows from table A joined to all rows in table B). What common columns do the `ACCOUNT` and `PHONE` tables have?

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I know that this is very expensive query by looking at the time consumed for it to execute, which is around 40 mins. But, how can i optimize it. If i get the data from only one table instead of 2 different tables, its works perfect! And again, the query is good, if DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE phase is removed, works perfect again! Problem comes if i try to fetch data from 2 different tables.

Comment: @BobJarvis There are around 25 similar common columns between 'ACCOUNT' and 'PHONE' tables. But, from my query, 'account_status' and 'account_type' are common.

Comment: So how do you know which phone number(s) are associated with a particular account?

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry, there was one more statement which is missed in question which is 'ac.account = ph.phone_account'  same account number will be mentioned as 'account' in account table and 'phone_account' in phone table. Edited my question now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I think the join and the randomisation in this case is consuming a lot of memory dynamically at runtime. You should rather limit your join on some condition or set the Dbms_Random.value to be limited because it is exceeding the temp space as the error itself.

Comment: How can i limit DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE?

Comment: If u can write in where clause Dbms_Random.value <{some_no} because it may happen the random value could be sometimes within some limit that may have given you the output at that point and sometimes it can increase beyond the actual temp segment size

Comment: Thank You Himanshu. My final query is like; 'select * from (select ac.account, ph.phone_no
from account ac, phone ph
and ac.account_status = 'OPEN'
and ac.account_type ='1'             
and ac.account_sub_type ='2' and DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE < (some number)
order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
where rownum = '1';'

Comment: great  @sandeep hegde